# Hit by two different drivers

Tags: insurance, utah

Couple of months my car got hit while parked , I got the other persons insurance information and I took forever to fail the claim til last week. The other person insurance too full liability, but I haven't fix the small dent.

Today a lady hit me on the same side ! And made more damage ! What happens now ?